# Scalar Multipliction Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to multiply a scalar value to a numpy array starting from a specific element.

eg) 3 * [1,1,1,1,1,1] = [1,3,3,3,3,3]

I have tried to do `np.dot(value, arr[1:])`, but this removes the first element. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is your data a numpy array or a python array? For numpy array:

```
a[1:] *= 3
```

For python array:

```
for i in range(1,len(a)): a[i] *= 3
```

**Note**: Of course the python approach works for numpy arrays as well, but it wouldn't take advantage of numpy's vectorization.

Comment: Python list, not array

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = np.array([1,1,1,1])
arr[1:] *= 2
```

or

```
arr = np.array([1,1,1,1])
arr[1:] = 2*arr[1:]
```

gives

```
arr->array([1, 2, 2, 2])
```